# Typescript Error: TS2339:Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

It seem typescript doesn't currently have the new object types in ECMAScript 2015 (6th Edition, ECMA-262).  Here is my code:

```
const SkipAny: string = requestBody.SkipAny;
CurTester.SkipAny = SkipAny.map((value)=>{return new RegExp(value)});
```

The error I get is:

```
TS2339:Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'
```

I would like to find a work around for this but I do want to use map.  Is there anyway to ignore this rule in tslint?

Comment: The error is completely correct.  Did you mean to use an array?

Comment: If you really intended to do this with a string, you'll need to `split()` the string first.

Comment: Ah yes, you guys are correct, SkipAny should be string array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the error is correct, I should had used array:

```
const SkipAny: string [] = requestBody.SkipAny;
CurTester.SkipAny = SkipAny.map((value)=>{return new RegExp(value)});
```