# React map over the children of the child

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this component that can take a single child or multipipe children, here it is with multiple

```
<SideDataGridItem>
   <div id='top'>
      <div>A1</div>
      <div>B1</div>
      <div>C1</div>
   </div>
   <div id='bottom'>
       <div>A2-</div>
       <div>B2-</div>
       <div>C2-</div>
    </div>
 </SideDataGridItem>
```

and here it is with a single child

```
<SideDataGridItem>
   <div id='top'>
      <div>A1</div>
      <div>B1</div>
      <div>C1</div>
   </div>
 </SideDataGridItem>
```

I want to be able to map over the children of the child.

Here's my attempt that doesn't work...

```
import { ReactElement, Children } from 'react';

export interface PropsShape {
  children: ReactElement | ReactElement[];
}

const SideDataGridItem = ({ children }: PropsShape): ReactElement => {
  const childArr = Children.toArray(children);
  return (
    <>
      {childArr[0] &&
        childArr[0].map(function (item: any, i: number) {
          return (
            <div key={i}>
              {item}- {i}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      {childArr[1] &&
        childArr[1].map(function (item: any, i: number) {
          return (
            <div key={i}>
              {item}- {i}
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
};
export { SideDataGridItem };
```

the error I get is a red squiggle on the .map...

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal'.
  Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

because it's trying to loop over a single item when really I want to loop over its children!

the correct answer will not output a div with an id of 'top' or 'bottom' it will simply map over the children of that div with the id

**Attempt 2**

```
import { ReactElement, Children } from 'react';

export interface PropsShape {
  children: ReactElement | ReactElement[];
}

const SideDataGridItem = ({ children }: PropsShape): ReactElement => {
  const childArr = Children.toArray(children);
  return (
    <>
    // map over the childArr
      {childArr.map(function (item: any) {
        // for each item inside the childArr map over them ?? expecting just 3 items not 4 or 1
        {
          item.map(function (itemInner: any, i: number) {
            return (
              <div key={i}>
                {itemInner}- {i}
              </div>
            );
          });
        }
      })}
    </>
  );
};
export { SideDataGridItem };
```

**Attempt 3**

If I log out `childArr` I get
[image]
Here we can see the array of the 3 items I want to map over in `childArr[0].props.children`

when I try and map over it I get

```
      {childArr[0] &&
        childArr[0].props.children.map(function (item: any, i: number) {
          return (
            <div key={i}>
              {item}- {i}
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

with the error

```
Property 'props' does not exist on type 'ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal'.
  Property 'props' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

Comment: `childArr[0]` is accessing the actual element at the given position which in `childArr` is your child. Try with just `childArr.map( ... )`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript Error: TS2339:Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52337944/typescript-error-ts2339property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-string)

Comment: childArr returns an array of children, for each child in childArr how do I loop over its children? I expect 3 HTML elements, not 4

Comment: Children.toArray(children); ensures its an array

Comment: Typescript Error: TS2339:Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string' does not answer this question, but thanks for the contribution

Comment: Sorry, my goof. As @Peppermintology pointed out, `childArr` might be an array type, but `childArr[0]` is a single object (`ReactElement`). The error is correct given the interface `PropsShape`'s definition of `children`. Either your interface is wrong, or you meant to do `childArr.map` instead of `childArr[0].map`, etc.

Comment: added `attempt 2` to try and show the problem with comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that (natively, without casting or ignoring errors, etc.), for a few reasons.

(Try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130270/unwrap-a-div-in-react-something-similar-to-jquery-unwrap-method) for an alternative).

#### 1. `children` can be a `ReactElement`

Consider this:

```
<SideDataGridItem><div /></SideDataGridItem>
```

This is a valid usage of your component according to the interface for `SideDataGridItem`'s props which allow for `ReactElement`, but the implementation breaks:

```
const SideDataGridItem = ({ children }: PropsShape): ReactElement => {
//                          ^ <div />
  const childArr = Children.toArray(children);
//      ^ [ <div /> ]
  return (
    <>
      {childArr[0] &&
//              ^ <div /> 
        childArr[0].map(function (item: any, i: number) {
{/*     ^^^^^^^^^^^ Error: "map" is not a property of a div!
```

TypeScript doesn't know for certain that the children of `childArr` have children of their own (which is likely solvable, but you have bigger problems).

#### 2. `ReactElement[]` is not declared how you think it is

TypeScript errors for the following:

```
const foo: ReactElement[] = ( 
  <div>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
);
```

Even though `div` can contain any number of children, it is not an array-like type. For example, you couldn't do:

```
  const bar = <ul><li></li></ul>;
  bar[0]; 
//^^^^^^ error
// Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't // be used to index type 'Element'.
//  Property '0' does not exist on type 'Element'
```

What TypeScript actually expects for `ReactElement[]` is something like:

```
const bar: ReactElement[] = [
  <div>Hello</div>,
  <div>There</div>
];
```

It's worth mentioning that all but the above examples are instances of `ReactElement` and not `ReactElement[]`. This also includes your question's example:

```
const example: ReactElement = <>
   <div id='top'>
      <div>A1</div>
      <div>B1</div>
      <div>C1</div>
   </div>
   <div id='bottom'>
       <div>A2-</div>
       <div>B2-</div>
       <div>C2-</div>
    </div>
</>;
```

#### 3. The `JSX.Element` interface is very limited

The underlying type for every JSX expression is `JSX.Element`: this is the API TypeScript provides for typing JSX implementations (like React). Note that `JSX.Element` is **not** generic, and that is the main issue preventing you from doing what you want here.

This requires a better understanding of how JSX works in TypeScript, but the short version is: TypeScript doesn't track the children of JSX elements because the resources needed to track that greatly decrease performance (see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29818) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14729#issuecomment-989102402)).